# input based txt file searcher results in triggering else statement depending on the input

Tags: python, text

```
with open("10kkpw.txt", "r", encoding="utf-8") as f:
    text = f.read()

for line in text:
    search = input("What are you looking for ")
    if search in line:
        print(line)
    else:
        print("Nope")
        break
```

Hello,

I have a major (from my perspective) problem. I tried to code my searcher and I'm stuck with a weird problem.

As you can see, my program opens a text file that is predetermined as a parameter of open function.
Nothing spectacular for now.
The text file consists of a list with data.

1. When I try to print out "text" variable, it prints out a list and it looks just like in the text file.
2. When I try to print out the text variable by using for loop

```
for line in text:
    print(line)
```

It starts to print out each character independently.

That's why I change the "text" variable to

```
text = f.read().splitlines()
```

The problem starts when I want to use if/else statement in the "for loop":

Even in the simplest form

```
for line in text:
    search = "a"
    if search in line:
       print(line)
    else:
        print("nope")
    break
```

It goes straight to "else" statement and printing "nope" as an output.
The only case where it actually finds something in that particular file is when I try to look for "1".

In different file however, it sometimes is capable of finding more files, but it's not willing to find anything else than that, even if the file has physically the string I'm looking for.
On the other hand, that script can find certain characters that are not numbers in different file.

What could be cause of this weird behaviour?
Or perhaps it works as intended?

Regards, Daniel.

Comment: There are different versions of your code in your question, that makes it rather unfocused. Could you concentrate it on one version of the code and one question? You should provide the exact code you're running, in one block that we could copy/paste, with some well chosen sample data, and the output vs expected output.

Comment: Note that in the first part, you read the whole file as a single string `text`, then iterate on it, so you iterate char by char. Just do `with open(...) as f:  for line in f:` to iterate line by line.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried switching `read()` to `readlines()`?
If you just use `read()` it will give you all the lines concatenated together with `\n`.

```py
with open("10kkpw.txt", "r", encoding="utf-8") as f:
    text = f.readlines()
print(text)

for line in text:
    search = input("What are you looking for ")
    if search in line:
        print(line)
    else:
        print("Nope")
        break
```

I notice that you did try `f.read().splitlines()` which should be equivalent.  If you can provide the first few lines of an example text file, that may provide information that will help with debugging.

Comment: ``` 123456
password
12345678
qwerty
123456789
12345
1234
111111
1234567
dragon
123123
baseball
abc123 ```

Comment: Just to make sure I have a clear picture: 123456 is the first line, password is the second line, 12345678 is the third line, and so on?

Comment: Exactly, they are all in the "new lines"

Comment: Hmm... This works as expected for me.  If you add `print(text)` like shown above do you get `['123456', 'password', ..., 'abc123']` as your output?

Comment: If I use splitlines(), I get the exactly the same result.

Comment: I'm not certain why we get different results.  As for debugging, I would recommend printing search and printing line immediately before entering the if statement.  This will show you which line is triggering the else statement and hopefully help locate the bug.